# Can't get regex to work. Empty returns

Tags: php, regex

I've tried this regex on three different "regex generators" online. It works fine. But when I run it on my local machine I get empty arrays as response.

This is my code.

```
$string = "Testing \$test;";
preg_match_all("/(\$[A-Za-z]*)/", $string, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Response is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

)
```

I've tried http://regexr.com/, https://regex101.com/#pcre, http://www.phpliveregex.com/
All work fine.

What is going on? Why is `preg_match_all` returning empty values on my machine? How can I debug this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `preg_match_all('/(\$[A-Za-z]*)/', $string, $match);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you used a double quoted string literal, you need to double backslashes:

```
preg_match_all("/(\\$[A-Za-z]*)/", $string, $match);
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/QwnAcZ)

Otherwise, the `$` with characters after it is parsed as a variable to expand.

That is why in most cases, a single quoted literal is preferred ([demo](https://ideone.com/iVZXol)) (as no variable expansion is expected inside it):

```
preg_match_all('/(\$[A-Za-z]*)/', $string, $match);
```

Comment: It works fine, I had no idea about this. Thanks for the information :)